# Whitelisting IP Addresses in Azure Docker Swarm

Tags: azure, docker, networking, ip-address, docker-swarm

I have a Docker Swarm consisting of 3 manager nodes and 3 worker nodes that I've deployed using Docker EE for Azure.  One of my services makes a call to an external third party API which requires the IP address calling the API to be whitelisted.

I've whitelisted the IP address for the External Load Balancer, however I'm intermittently receiving responses from the API that suggest the IP from where the API is being called isn't whitelisted.

Are there any other IP addresses that it would be standard to whitelist in addition to the one for the External Load Balancer, and if so, where would I find these, or is my initial understanding that all requests would come from the same IP correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outbound connections are likely not using the incoming load balancer. Run a container that resolves your client IP through curl, for example:

`docker run bretfisher/netshoot curl -s checkip.dyndns.org`

Comment: Thanks for this Bret.  I found out that the manager nodes were using the SSH IP address which I'd not whitelisted and the workers were using the external load balancing IP address which had been whitelisted.  Whether services were running on managers or workers would then determine whether a token could be obtained.  The managers have now been drained meaning services are only running on the workers and so requests are only coming from the whitelisted IP.